Can I determine earthly latitude by position of lunar mare
I am thinking that geographical latitude or at least whether you are in the northern hemisphere or southern hemisphere could be determined by the position of lunar mare. For example, if you see that Mare Fecunditatis (Sea of Fertility) is in the south east (5:00 on a clock position) on the face of the moon, then you are observing from the northern hemisphere. However, if the Sea of Fertility / Fecundity is at the north west (11 o’clock position) on the face of the moon, then you are in the southern hemisphere. Is this true? What about if you are viewing the Moon from the Earth’s equator? Could this approach also be used to make an approximate estimation of latitude whether or not you view the Moon after sunset or even during day time when the Sun is up?

Overall, yes, your reasoning is good. However, it is slightly complicated by the tilt of the Moon’s orbit, for example, and you are also right about complications around the equator, where it’s not so easy to figure out.

Latitude can be easily determined by the altitude of the pole.  It's slightly trickier in the southern hemisphere to locate the pole but a lot easier than using the angle of the moon.

When viewing the Moon from the surface of the Earth, the "clock position" of features seen on the moon relative to the horizon  generally rotates by about 180 degrees between moonrise and moonset

Short answer is yes, but the longer answer is it's generally easier to use something else.  You can also get a sense of your latitude from the Sun, or any star/constellation in the same way.  What you're referring to is similar to a "Noon Sighting" or "Transit Method" of celestial navigation, but much more rough.  Generally people already know which hemisphere they're in without looking at anything, unless you're traveling very near the equator, in which case your method would be very tough to use, but the "Noon Sighting" still works.
